# Tkinter Notebook removing shadow

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

Is it possible to remove the [image: shadow of the Notebook]?
(there is a notebook with 'next' inside another one)
Already tried `borderwidth` and `highlightthicknes`

My theme:

```
style = ttk.Style()
        style.theme_create("mytheme", parent="alt", settings={
            "Tab": {"configure": []},
            'Canvas': {'configure': {'bd' : -2}},
            "TFrame": {"configure": {'borderwidth': -10, 'highlightthicknes': 0}},
            "TNotebook": {
                "configure": {"background": 'red', "tabmargins": [-2, -2, -2, -2]}}
        }
                           )
        style.theme_use("mytheme")
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.layout('TNotebook.Tab', [])
        style.layout('TNotebook.padding', [])
```

Comment: ***remove the shadow***: What do you mean by shadow? According to [STYLING OPTIONS](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm#M38) there is only `bordercolor` styling options configurable with ttk::style.

Comment: You can see it on the image, on bottom and right sides

Answer (score 0):

Use borderwidth: 0 on the notebook element